# Issue using DotNetCoreCLI@2 to build a dacpac: Are Azure DevOps Build Pipelines Dependent on the project file

Tags: build, azure-pipelines, sqlproj

We are setting up a build pipeline in our locally hosted Azure Devops environment to create a dacpac from a Visual Studio SQL project.

We are developing using Visual Studio 2022.

We are having issues using both the **DotNetCoreCLI@2** and **VSBuild@1** tasks.

For **DotNetCoreCLI@2** we are getting the error

```
##
[error]NET\MySolution\MySolution.Database\MySolution.Database.sqlproj(56,3): 
Error MSB4019: 
The imported project "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" was not found.
Confirm that the expression in the Import declaration 
"C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets"
is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
```

We have installed the SDK on the build server but as I understand it that is all that is needed. Visual Studio should not need to be on it.

**Is that correct?**

For **VSBuild@1** we are getting the error

```
##[error]C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v16.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets(573,5): 
Error MSB4181: The "SqlBuildTask" task returned false but did not log an error.
```

We have other build pipelines happening on the same server but they do not have this issue.

Obviously we would like to get a fix for this so if anyone has any suggestions, we would be grateful.

Over and above that, The impression I get from errors I have experienced, is that whatever is in the project file has an influence on how a build pipeline executes.

The first issue above is a case in point. "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" is not specified in the buld pipeline but in the project there is the following

```
 <PropertyGroup>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(VisualStudioVersion)' == ''">11.0</VisualStudioVersion>
    <!-- Default to the v11.0 targets path if the targets file for the current VS version is not found -->
    <SSDTExists Condition="Exists('$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets')">True</SSDTExists>
    <VisualStudioVersion Condition="'$(SSDTExists)' == ''">11.0</VisualStudioVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Condition="'$(SQLDBExtensionsRefPath)' != ''" Project="$(SQLDBExtensionsRefPath)\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" />
  <Import Condition="'$(SQLDBExtensionsRefPath)' == ''" Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v$(VisualStudioVersion)\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks.targets" />
```

Presumably this is what is driving the cause of the error.

However I cannot find any documentation discussing if project configuration influences build pipelines.

**Does anyone have any insight on that?**

Thanks

Comment: As per the error, have you firstly check the path `C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.100\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\SSDT\Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.SqlTasks` on your agent machine, is it correct? Please share your pipeline definitions for more details.